# How to understand this label on part?

Tags: identification, components, thermal

From the label on thermostat I can read the following, but can't decode it to understand the max current.

[image]

```
CAMPINI Ty 95 

C1-16(3)/250~ 
C2-6(1)/250~
```

Does anyone know what is the 16(3) and 6(1) means? The device(oven) has 1.15KW power mentioned on the back? I am trying to substitude this thermostat with simple relay, but would like to get one with proper current. Wires connected to it and thermo elemt are 2mm thick, if that helps.

Comment: Datasheet, photo, manufacturer name, ...

Comment: Well, having datasheet I would also figure out :) I thought that this marking is some standard. Picture is [here](http://www.campinicorel.it/cmsCampiniFiles/image/prodotti_foto-TY95V.jpg). Name is `CAMPINI Ty 95`.

Comment: The [product page](http://www.campinicorel.it/cmsCampini/Prodotti/pagina_Prodotto_en-19.html) says `Rated voltage and current: 16(3) A/ 250V ca`. But still I don't understand if it's `16A` or `3A`?

Comment: I think this is related to something inductive heating. Inductive load means when work-piece getting heated using inductive heating method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [certification datasheet](http://www.campinicorel.it/cmsCampiniFiles/pdf/Certificazioni-ty95.pdf) (warning opens *.pdf) you get the following:
[image: From datasheet]

resistive vs. inductive load rating.

Comment: So oven is using Inductive thermal element since the maximum rated power is mentioned `1.15kw` on the back side, near power cable, for `220V`.